# Best way to insert data to multiple table MVC ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have 4 tables. OperationTable, ClientTable, ClientDetails, OperationRes

ClientTable

- ClientID
- Name
- Surname
- Birthday
- VerNumber

ClientDetails

- ClientID
- Email
- Adress
- Telephone

OperationTable

- OperationID
- Date
- Time
- ClientID

OperationRes

- ResID
- OperationID
- Name
- Type
- No

i have page where we ask Client to fill a form to register for smth. Everything must be in one page and after Client submit the form, we must insert all data to it's table. Date and Time to OperationTable, Name and Surname to ClientTable and so on.
I'm new in ASP.NET MVC. i have tried to use "Code Fisrt". I have created Model and just used it to autogenerate View and Controller. but it's not what i want. i've found this [Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/651495/Inserting-Data-into-Multiple-Tables-using-Code-Fir). it works! But i have more than 4 tables which and more rows than i write above. what is the best solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want a view model that holds all the data you want to insert, then in your controller create the objects based on that view model and insert using EF.  Something like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Birthday {get; set;}
    public string VerNumber { get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
    // etc etc for the rest of your data
}
```

Then in your controller, use your ViewModel to populate your entities, then insert using EF:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(MyViewModel model)
{
     var client = new Client{
          Name = model.Name,
          Birthday = model.Birthday
     };

     var clientDetails = new ClientDetails();

     //etc for your other entities

     using (var context = new MyDbContext)
     {
          context.Clients.Add(client);
          clientDetails.ClientId = client.Id;
          context.ClientDetails.Add(clientDetails);
          //etc add your other classes
          context.SaveChanges();

     }

     //whatever you want to do here for the result, maybe direct to new controller
     //or return view
     return View();

}
```

You may want to look at tidying up the entity framework code using a [Repository Pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)  and you could also look at [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to map entities from your viewmodel, to save doing it manually.

Comment: thanks a lot for detailed answer. is it normal if MyViewModel grows. 1)Name 2) Surname 3)Birthday ... 50) smth.? or is there other solution except creating view model. thanks in advance

Comment: If you are wanting the user to enter/edit data from different tables then yes you'll definitely need a viewmodel, there are also security advantages of using viewmodels rather than entities, due to over positing attacks.

Comment: Just doing the same thing the other way around, load your entities from the database, then have a viewmodel to display the combined data, assign the values to the viewmodel and return it from your controller

Comment: Can you give an example link please. i google it, nothing works for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: That didn't work... I can't post the details in the comments but there are loads of tutorials and articles on asp.net http://www.asp.net/mvc   You can also try: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Using-Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-M  Take a look towards the bottom of the page, is where it mentions view models.

Comment: i've tried you first example and it's works for showing current users details controller/action/id. Now still searching for show all data from tables. thanks for link, i'm sure i'm one the right way.

Answer (score 3):

Logically, your operation will be exactly same as the tutorial show. only you have to create ViewModel which contains all the 4 table fields.

Then when the form post back, do your logic of deciding which field in ViewModel goes to which tables' model. Then save that table model.

In the tutorial it use one ViewModel (LoginViewModel) and save to two table (Login, User). In you case just save to 4 (OperationTable, ClientTable, ClientDetails, OperationRes).